# Kotlin conversion to Javascript error: "subtract is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, kotlin

I'm having an issue when converting a Kotlin code to JavaScript. Whenever I use subtraction or addition, it converts to an invalid JavaScript code.

I have a Kotlin JavaScript project, configured with Gradle. The compiler is configured to generate output to commonjs, and I created a simple NodeJS application to execute the generated code.

Original Kotlin file:

```
import kotlin.js.JsName

@JsName("testSubtraction")
fun testSubtraction(a: Long, b: Long) : Long {
    return a - b
}
```

Generated output file:

```
module.exports = function (Kotlin) {
  'use strict';
  var _ = Kotlin.defineRootPackage(null, /** @lends _ */ {
    testSubtraction: function (a, b) {
      return a.subtract(b);
    }
  });
  Kotlin.defineModule('output', _);
  return _;
}(require('kotlin'));

//@ sourceMappingURL=output.js.map
```

The error that I get when executing the code is:
**TypeError: a.subtract is not a function**

I have tested using Kotlin 1.0.5-2 and 1.1-M03, but they both convert with this same problem.

### How do I solve this problem?

The workaround solution that I have found so far is defining this method manually in my application, but I didn't like it:

```
Number.prototype.subtract = function(a) {
    return this.valueOf() - a;
}
```

I have created a sample project to demonstrate this issue at GitHub: https://github.com/leandro-dev/test_kotlin_js

Comment: Do you have the standard library included?

Comment: I included only the files generated by Kotlin.
The kotlin.js file is at node_modules folder, so it's included.
I referenced the generated output.js javascript file (that requires kotlin.js to work) and called the function testSubtraction.

Comment: Did you install kotlin.js manually? I don't see it in package.json?

Comment: Yes. It's a file generated by Gradle, that will be created under node_modules. I first build with gradle to convert the kotlin to JavaScript, and then I run the NodeJS application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin `Long` is not JS `number` and the problem is that you call `testSubtraction` with JS numbers.

If you want to work with JS `number` use `Int` in Kotlin code.

If you want to pass JS `number` where Kotlin expected `Long` use `Kotlin.Long.fromNumber` or `Kotlin.Long.fromInt` to create `Long`